# Mockito can't inject mocks

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, integration-testing

I'm using Mockito and I'm trying to inject a Mock CustomFileHandler into my REjercicioDAO class for testing purposes. The thing is, my test throws no exceptions, but it doesn't inject my mock object, the original @Autowired CustomFileHandler is not being substituted. Here's my code:

```
@Repository
public class REjercicioDAO extends ARHibernateDAO < REjercicio > implements IREjercicioDAO {

    @Autowired
    public ICustomFileHandler customFileHandler;

    ...

}
```

And here's my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ATest.CONTEXT_CONFIGURATION)
public class REjercicioDAOTest extends ATest {

    @Mock private ICustomFileHandler customFileHandler;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private IREjercicioDAO rEjercicioDAO;

    @Before
    public void before () {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        ...

    }
```

Btw, entities work as expected and interfaces are correctly linked to the actual entities, I have tested that. How can I fix this?

Comment: Guessing: the autowired annotation within the test code... Try removing that one. I rather doubt that putting two annotations like that on the same field will do any good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a no answer. I could not give more because I am really sorry to see so many people use this awkward API relying on reflection while you could do things really clear for the readers of the class by explicitly setting the dependency.

> The thing is, my test throws no exceptions, but it doesn't inject my
>   mock object

Not surprising. This way of injecting the mock stays quiet even if no injection succeeds.   [From the `InjectMocks`  javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) (emphasis is not mine!) :

> Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection,
>   setter injection, or property injection in order and as described
>   below. If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito **won't
>   report failure;** i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.

While Mockito does not report failure, I really discourage to use this API.

About your actual issue, look at that :

```
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
private IREjercicioDAO rEjercicioDAO;
```

You annotate the field with both Spring and Mockito annotation. Do you feel confortable with the order of their processing ? These come from two distinct libraries. I don't tell that it will never work (luck and random exists) but do you really think that it is robust ?

To achieve your requirement you could write something like that that does things in two explicit steps :
- objects instantiation : mocking the dependency and inject the spring dependency
- relationship set : between the mock dependency and the spring dependency

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ATest.CONTEXT_CONFIGURATION)
public class REjercicioDAOTest extends ATest {

    @Mock 
    private ICustomFileHandler customFileHandler;

    @Autowired        
    private IREjercicioDAO rEjercicioDAO;

    @Before
    public void before () {    
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // Set explicitly the fileHandler dependency
        rEjercicioDAO.setFileHandler(customFileHandler);         
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm just gonna use a setter for the dependency because it's easier than dealing with library configuration and integration

Comment: No : thanks to you for changing your approach ! Easier and also really clearer !

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to mix IT with a unit test.

**1)** If you are using Spring Boot:

```
@MockBean
private ICustomFileHandler customFileHandler;

@Autowired
private IREjercicioDAO rEjercicioDAO;
```

Thats it..

**2)** Not using Spring Boot:

```
public class TestConfig{

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ICustomFileHandler customFileHandler(){
       return Mockito.mock(ICustomFileHandler.class);
    }

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ATest.CONTEXT_CONFIGURATION, classes=TestConfig.class)
public class REjercicioDAOTest extends ATest {

   @Autowired
   private ICustomFileHandler customFileHandlerMock; 

    @Autowired
    private IREjercicioDAO rEjercicioDAO;
```

The mock gets injected and you can set it up in your test as you like

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, what do you mean I'm mixing IT and unit? I'm trying to unit test REjercicioDAO, that's why I'm trying to mock the dependency, so I can test the methods in isolation of other external entities

Comment: You do not Autowire and start the context in a unit test ;)

Comment: I think I'm not getting it. Why would I not want to autowire if what I'm testing is the autowired class, of which I need an entity to perform tests with?

Comment: Maybe you actually need a unit test.. but you do not need stuff like SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and Autowiring in that case.. you do not need any framework specific stuff in a unit test

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being dumb, I'm kinda new to testing, but wouldn't I still "need" to mock entities? I need some way to make sure the dependencies in my code return some known values, so I can test the rest of the code in isolation. If that is the case, then I need a framework like mockito, or to make mock classes myself but I've read that is not such a good idea

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I just realized why I don't need context or spring runners. Thank you for your patience xD